# Number of vectors $(x_1,...,x_n)$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^nx_i \leq k$ where $x_i$ is a positive integer

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

The problem goes like this:

> Determine the number of vectors $(x_1,...,x_n)$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^nx_i \leq k$ where $x_i$ is a positive integer and $k \geq n$

Notice the operator $\leq$. Its not $=$, in which case it turns out to be [star and bar problem theorem 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Theorem_one).

How do I approach this one?

**Update**

Ok I found solution at the end of the exercise. But the explanation is fuzzy. It goes like this:

> Since there are $\binom{j-1}{n-1}$ positive vectors whose sum is $j$, there must be $\sum_{j=n}^k\binom{j-1}{n-1}$ such vectors. But $\binom{j-1}{n-1}$ is the number of subsets of size $n$ from the set of numbers $\{1,...,k\}$ in which $j$ is largest element in the subset. Consequently, $\sum_{j=n}^k\binom{j-1}{n-1}$ is just the total number of subsets of size $n$ from a set of size $k$, showing that the preceding answer is equal to $\binom{k}{n}.$

I didn't get from the second sentence "But...".

Comment: The link contains a proof. Do you have trouble following any particular part of it?

Comment: I guess the link provides the proof for $x_1+...+x_n\color{red}{=}k$, but not for $x_1+...+x_n\color{red}{<=}k$. Am I missing something?

Comment: When you say $x_i$ positive, do you mean $x_1 > 0$ or $x_i \geq 0$ ?

Comment: I meant $x_1>0$

Comment: Please, take the habit to use Latex conventions: I have replaced your $>=$ (resp. "<=") by "backslash symbol" followed by the 3 letters "geq" (resp followed by "leq"). I have also replaced "Sigma" by "sum".

Answer (score 2):

You could introduce an extra variable $x_{n+1}$ defined to
be $k+1-\sum_{i=1}^nx_i$.

Comment: Why $k+1$ rather than just $k$?

Comment: @OpenBall To me, positive means $>0$; the French disagree, but what else can you expect?

Comment: please see the update to the original post/question

Answer (score 0):

Although I prefer the other answer, another possibility is for each $l=n,n+1,\dots,k$ finding the number of solutions to

$$\sum_{i=1}^nx_i=n$$

(via stars and bars, like you linked) and then adding those values. Notice that $l=n$ is the smallest value $\sum x_i$ may assume if the $x_i\geq 1$, ie, they are positive.

Comment: please see the update to the original post/question

Comment: The second sentence remarks the following: consider a subset of $\{1,2,\dots,k\}$ with $n$ elements and in which $j\geq n$ is the largest element. How many such subsets are there? To produce one such subset, it suffices to choose $n-1$ elements from $\{1,2,\dots,j-1\}$ -- the resulting subset, together with $j$, will be as desired. Finally, there are $\binom{j-1}{n-1}$ ways to make that choice.